# How can I create a Protocol that encompases both threading.Event and multiprocessing.Event?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

In the Python standard library `multiprocessing.Event` is explicitly stated to be a clone of `threading.Event` and to have the same interface.  I would like to annotate variables and arguments so that they can accept either of those classes, and `mypy` would type-check them.  I tried creating a Protocol (I used `multiprocessing.synchronize.Event` since that is the actual class that is returned by `multiprocessing.Event`).

```py
import multiprocessing
import threading

from typing import Optional, Type, Protocol


class Event(Protocol):
    def wait(self, timeout: Optional[float]) -> bool:
        ...

    def set(self) -> None:
        ...

    def clear(self) -> None:
        ...

    def is_set(self) -> bool:
        ...


class Base:
    flag_class: Type[Event]

    def foo(self, e: Event):
        pass


class DerivedOne(Base):
    flag_class = multiprocessing.synchronize.Event

    def foo(self, e: multiprocessing.synchronize.Event):
        pass


class DerivedTwo(Base):
    flag_class = threading.Event

    def foo(self, e: threading.Event):
        pass
```

However, `mypy` (version 0.761) doesn't recognize that `multiprocessing.Event` and `threading.Event` both implement the protocol I defined:

```sh
$ mypy proto.py

proto.py:31: error: Argument 1 of "foo" is incompatible with supertype "Base"; supertype defines the argument type as "Event"
proto.py:38: error: Argument 1 of "foo" is incompatible with supertype "Base"; supertype defines the argument type as "Event"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Why doesn't `mypy` recognize my protocol and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a `Protocol` issue. You altering the signature of `foo` to *stricter variants*. `Base.foo()` accepts **any** `Event` implementation, while your subclasses each only accept a single concrete implementation. That's a violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and Mypy is correct in not allowing this.

You'd have to use a combination of a bound `TypeVar` and `Generic` here, so you can create different concrete subclasses of `Base` that take a different type:

```
from typing import Generic, Optional, Protocol, Type, TypeVar

# Only things that implement Event will do
T = TypeVar("T", bound=Event)

# Base is Generic, subclasses need to state what exact class
# they use for T; as long as it's an Event implementation, that is.
class Base(Generic[T]):
    flag_class: Type[T]

    def foo(self, e: T) -> None:
        pass
```

This essentially makes `Base` a kind of template class, with `T` the template slot you can plug anything into, as long as that *anything* implements your protocol. This is also far more robust as you now can't accidentally mix up the `Event` implementations (combining `threading.Event` and `multiprocessing.Event` in a single subclass).

So the following subclasses for the two different `Event` implementations are correct:

```
class DerivedOne(Base[multiprocessing.synchronize.Event]):
    flag_class = multiprocessing.synchronize.Event

    def foo(self, e: multiprocessing.synchronize.Event) -> None:
        pass

class DerivedTwo(Base[threading.Event]):
    flag_class = threading.Event

    def foo(self, e: threading.Event) -> None:
        pass
```

but using a class that doesn't implement the protocol methods is an error:

```
# Mypy flags the following class definition as an error, because a lock
# does not implement the methods of an event.
# error: Type argument "threading.Lock" of "Base" must be a subtype of "proto.Event"
class Wrong(Base[threading.Lock]):
    flag_class = threading.Lock

    def foo(self, e: threading.Lock) -> None:
        pass
```

It is also an error to mix the types:

```
# Mypy flags 'def foo' as an error because the type it accepts differs from
# the declared type of the Base[...] subclass
# error: Argument 1 of "foo" is incompatible with supertype "Base"; supertype defines the argument type as "Event"
class AlsoWrong(Base[threading.Event]):
    flag_class = threading.Event

    def foo(self, e: multiprocessing.synchronize.Event) -> None:
        pass

# Mypy flags 'flag_class' as an error because the type differs from the
# declared type of the Base[...] subclass
# error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[multiprocessing.synchronize.Event]", base class "Base" defined the type as "Type[threading.Event]")
class StillWrong(Base[threading.Event]):
    flag_class = multiprocessing.synchronize.Event

    def foo(self, e: threading.Event) -> None:
        pass
```